# GSM modem stops responding after CMGL and CMGR commands

Tags: gsm, modem

I have an LG B470 flip phone. I want to be able to send and receive text messages from my Mac Laptop running OS X 10.10.5.

I have the phone plugged in via USB. I can send SMS messages using the minicom terminal. However, attempting to list or read SMS messages from the phone/modem causes the modem to stop responding:

```
AT
OK
ATI
Manufacturer: LG ELECTRONICS
Model: LGB470
Revision: LGB470-QSC6270-V10c-JAN-11-2016-ATT-US  1  [JAN 11 2016 22:00:00]
SVN: 01
IMEI: 359926084167819
+GCAP: +CGSM,+DS,+ES

OK
AT+CPMS?
+CPMS: "ME",15,500,"ME",15,500,"SM",0,30

OK
AT+CMGF=1
OK
AT+CMGS="+12146168895"
> Hello World. 

+CMGS: 169

OK
AT+CMGL="ALL"
```

I get no response and can no longer communicate at all. Typing is not echoed back and if I turn local echoing on and attempt to send the `AT` command I get no response. The only way to get the modem to respond is by restarting the phone (unplugging and plugging back in the phone's USB, etc. does not help).

The same thing happens after `AT+CMGR` commands.

### Question

Why does the phone/modem stop responding after `AT+CMGL` and `AT+CMGR` commands? How can I fix this so I can get incoming SMS messages from my phone to my mac? Any tips on how to debug?

### Setup

I did not install any drivers. When I plugged my phone into my mac via USB it was recognized automatically. It is shown as an internet modem in System Preferences->Network. Some character devices were also created:

```
$ ll /dev/tty.*
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,   4 Apr 20 13:27 /dev/tty.BIGJAMBOXbyJawbone-SPPD
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,   2 Apr 20 13:27 /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,   0 Apr 20 13:27 /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,   6 Apr 20 13:27 /dev/tty.LGB470-LGPCSuite
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,  12 Apr 20 13:46 /dev/tty.lgusbmodem1411
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,  14 Apr 20 13:46 /dev/tty.lgusbserial1411
```

`tty.lgusbmodem1411` (lg usb modem 1411) and `tty.lgusbserial1411` (lg usb serial 1411) disappear and reappear when I unplug and plug in the phone's USB. `tty.LGB470-LGPCSuite` is always there and seems to reference the [LG PC Suite](http://www.lg.com/us/support/product-help/CT10000026-20150108669720-lg-backup-lg-switch) software which is not compatible with my phone.

I can also connect to it via Bluetooth and transfer files via the "Bluetooth File Exchange" app.

`minirc.dfl`:

```
pu port             /dev/tty.lgusbmodem1411
pu lock             /usr/local/Cellar/minicom/2.7.1/var
pu escape-key       Escape (Meta)
```

### Additional Info

As reported by the `ATI` command, my LGB470 phone uses the [Qualcomm QSC6270](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/download_datasheet.php?id=1475846&part-number=QSC6270) "HEDGE (HSDPA/WCDMA and GSM/GPRS/EDGE)" chipset. I can not find documentation on the GSM modem/AT commands, however.

Comment: It looks like you may have run into a firmware bug of the modem. Could you try with a different device?

Comment: Does "device" refer to the modem or what I am using to send the AT commands? I do not have access to another modem. I tried to send AT commands from my Windows 10 PC but I was unsuccessful. If you think it will be helpful I can update my post with the details of my attempt.

Comment: I was actually thinking about the modem.

Comment: Are there alternate ways of reading SMS messages? Or perhaps different configurations that I could try to avoid the bug?